# How to use MySQL variables in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-variables

I am trying to do something like this:

```
SET @grade_id = (SELECT  grade_id FROM grades_table WHERE grades = '1' AND sections = 'A');
SET @subject_id = (SELECT subject_id FROM subjects_table WHERE grade_id = @grade_id AND subject_name = 'Maths' AND teacher_id = '1');
INSERT INTO topics_table ( subject_id, grade_id, topic_name) VALUES (@subject_id, @grade_id,'Another Topic');
```

This works in phpmyadmin but doesn't work when I use it with PHP in Visual Studio Code.
I'm doing this in VSC:

```
$topic = "SET @grade_id = (SELECT  grade_id FROM grades_table WHERE grades = '1' AND sections = 'A');
SET @subject_id = (SELECT subject_id FROM subjects_table WHERE grade_id = @grade_id AND subject_name = 'Maths' AND teacher_id = '1');
INSERT INTO topics_table ( subject_id, grade_id, topic_name) VALUES (@subject_id, @grade_id,'Another Topic')"; 

mysqli_multi_query(
    $connection,
    $topic
);
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: I don't have a place to test this right now, however it appears as though $topic should be an ongoing concatenation, not three lines separated by \n or whatever this is using. try:
`$topic = "set...`
`$topic .= "set...`
`$topic .= "insert...`

I'm not sure it matters, but maybe a line break is causing the issue. Otherwise, to my knowledge, this looks fine.

Comment: Also, just as a quick aside, if you have access you could create these as stored procedures, and then use a single query to execute them using CALL.

Comment: **Never use `mysqli_multi_query()`**